# Storing an List of Objects in DynamoDB and retrieving them partially

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

This might two separate questions into a single one. But that's my current use case. I have a POJO which has specific attributes.

It might look like:

```
class MyObject {
    String id;
    String name;
    int size;

getters and setters () ....
}
```

Now I have a list of these objects - List which I wish to store in a single in Dynamo. Something like

```
RecordID            Attributes
abcd123             List<MyObject>
```

Can I store the data in Dynamo in the above format? My second question is related to the above use case.

Now that I have stored the records, can I retrieve a specific part of the List? Like, I want indices 0 - 5 to be returned from the DyanmoDBQuery Request and not the entire list itself.

Is that possible?

I am pretty new to DynamoDB and I am not sure how well there is support for storing custom objects in Dynamo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to massage your schema and move to a Partition-Sort key schema, where the Partition key is RecordID and the Sort key is ItemNumber, where Item number is the index of each MyObject in the `abcd123` list above, then you can get sublists with a range query:

Item example:

```
RecordID (partition key) asdfasdfadsf
ItemNumber (sort key)    0
Item                     an instance of MyObject
```

Range query parameters:

```
KeyCondition: RecordId = :rid AND ItemNumber BETWEEN :lower AND :upper
ExpressionAttributeValues = { ":rid": "asdfasdfasdf", ":lower": 0, ":upper": 5 }
```

Note that the `:upper` bound is inclusive, so the query example above will return MyObjects with `RecordId=asdfasdfasdf` with ItemNumbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a class a class for the object you would like to store in the list and annotate it with the @DynamoDBDocument.

```
public class ObjectThatHasTheList {

    private List<ObjectInTheList> list;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "list")
    public List<ObjectInTheList> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    // setter
 }
```

Below is the class for the object you want to store in the list.

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class ObjectInTheList {

    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would work. have you tried it in production?

Comment: I don't have access to the code base I used this in anymore, but at the time it did work for me.

Comment: not working for me :(